# WordPress: How to show who delete post in wp

Tags: wordpress

I need to show who is editor has delete any post in my WordPress web site, I show some post in draft.

How can show that.. Are plugin do that ?

I cannot see it in revision

Comment: If my plugin suggestion was helpful, would you mind accepting it as the answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the Simple History plugin:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-history/

I believe it does what you're asking for. I've used this a few months back and was pretty happy with the extra info it provides.

Answer (score 0):

there is no way to know that in a normal installation.

You can download and install some plugin to do that, go to section plugins on wordpress site, this is an example: 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/aryo-activity-log/